# Where does input validation happen in MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Ok, this has probably been asked before but i cant find a definative answer.  Where in the MVC pattern should validation of input happen?

I would like to say that things like empty fields and basic general validation should happen in the controller and that rules as lengths and valid characters of for example usernames / passwords etc should happen at the model layer.

However, this means spreading this burdon around the application which surely cant be good either?

Sorry if this question is naieve but I am relatively new to this type of programming and want to get things correct from the start.

Comment: You're talking about PHP, so you might want to specify that you mean MVC and not MVP, the latter of which is more common in web frameworks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894815/validation-layer-in-mvc-pattern and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250548/php-where-should-validation-functions-be-stored

Answer (score 6):

Validation is the job of the model.

As models have various attributes (fields), only the models can know what combination of inputs make that model valid. It's not just about whether a field is blank, or the input of that field matches some pattern, but sometimes this is a combination of field inputs, or the model's relationship to other models that determine the valid state.

Your model should encapsulate this logic so you can interrogate it ("are you valid?") and not have it spread across other parts of your code.

Comment: It is impossible to do this all in the model without knowledge external to the model. While you can encapsulate the logic within the model the knowledge is going to move outside the model almost immediately. Once this happens it would be in your best interest to isolate concerns; leave the model as it sits, move the "external validation" to some other orchestrating type.

Answer (score 3):

There is no single answer. What will begin to surface is that validation can not solely happen at the model because the model does not have knowledge of its surroundings. A prime example of this is duplicate names where uniqueness matters form a visual stance. The moment that requirement surfaces, some sort of validation is going to take place external to the model or the model is going to have to become aware of its surroundings which begins the coupling.

I try to push as much as possible into the model, that is relative to the model/requirements. Once it extends beyond that the only other place to go is within the controller.

Comment: Shouldn't the model determine itself whether it's unique? Why would you put this in the controller? IMHO, the controller should only make decisions based on whether or not the model is valid, and not define the logic that makes it so.

Comment: @Andrew The questions is how much knowledge the model is going to have external to itself. If the model has knowledge of other models, then where do you draw the line? How do you stop the coupling amongst models and their interaction? It get's muddy to me. Which is why any validation that can happen within the model itself is fine, the point at which orchestration is needed bring in someone else and in this instance that would be the controller in a pure MVC environment. In reality I would probably have some other entity performing this logic, which would be neither the model or controller.

Answer (score 2):

I agree on the fact **there's no unique solution**.

I tend to keep **validation which is related to the logic of the application** in the **controller**. This has a great **advantage** in those cases where **the model can vary** (otherwise you need to replicate the checks in all models).

In the **model**, I just keep **validation which is dependent on the storage mechanism**.

The **view** could be a good place to implement some **client-side validation**, for immediate feedback.

Again, this is just my opinion.

Comment: Agreed! If the validation is simple, why not save the trip to the server?

Comment: Usually because you can't rely on client-side validation.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I validate in both the Controller as the Model, but I tend to stick to validation in the Controller *only* to be sure that a certain Model function should be loaded. So basically: validate in order to control.

Example: someone tries to update certain information posting a form to `?p=foo&bar=1&baz=2`. In the Controller I'd check whether the values 1 and 2 are actual numbers and it's a valid request. Maybe even do a check to see whether the user has access to this particular info.

If this is the case, I call on the update function in the Model which will then validate all the posted form data. If not, it usually means the user isn't supposed to be there in the first place and it doesn't even reach the Model.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrew. It's the model's job to take care of data validation. Of course you can validate wherever you want, but it's MVC best practice to do it inside the model.